# Ignore a GET variable from links, when downloading a website for offline

Tags: wget, httrack

Quite simply the site I'm downloading has every single link ending with `&sid=335345346fdsfdsfs`. That keeps changing and creates bunch of the same `index.html` and the same for many other pages.

I wonder if someone already has dealt with problems like this. All I need is `sed -e 's/&sid=.*$//g'` .

1. So the tool gets link from internet `http://foo.bar/&sid=yada`
2. Pre-processes it `http://foo.bar`
3. checks if it already exists, accordingly downloads or skips.
4. if downloads, replace do same `s/&sid=.*$//g` for links inside downloaded `.html`

If there is already some smart way to ignore GET variables embedded in site name, welcome.